# Update part of object (nested) in redux store using immer and es6 in a normalized data

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, ecmascript-6, normalization

I have a store with the global Update action

I would like to update only part of the data, I don't get full data that I can normalize again

my store is :

```
{
  store:{
      studentes:{
         "1": {
            "name": {
               "second": "xxx",
               "third": "bbbbb"
            }
            "age": 60 
             
          }
    }
  }
}
```

that is initialized after normalized the data

now I would like to update only the age

how can I achieve that with Es6 or immer?

I don't want to pass every variable in my object and update like:

```
  inside student reducer:

   draft[id].name.secondName = "boo"
   draft[id].name.thirdName = "xx"
```

I tried to that like :

```
 return draft = {..draft ,...data}
```

but this will replace all object

my server response is smth like :

```
 "data":{
     "name" : {
        "second" :"dddd"
     }
  }
```

here I got only part of the inner data

and it's a big object. so i am looking for smth generic for update

Answer (score 1):

As we have Object Destructuring in ES6 you can use that.

```
let draft = {
     ...draft,
     name: {
          ...draft.name,
          second: 'joe'
     }
}
```

So by this, the actual values in `draft` will be inserted in the new variable first. Then coming to the `name` key the `...draft.name` will insert all the values in `draft.name` into that key's value except the `second` key which will have the value `'joe'`.